# finding contours of a plant root

Tags: python, opencv, contour, edge-detection

I have an image which has roots like this:
[image]

I want to crop each root individually out.
I initially thought of heavy dilation followed by erosion and contour detection of the blob, but since the roots are thin, it does not work well.

I also directly applied canny edge and contour detection like this image below. It has around 62000 contours, but I cannot use it to get the outline of each root.
[image: after canny and contour detection on above image]

I also thresholded the image using HSV followed by some median blurring. But it did not reduce much noise. Further blurring only leads to losing the root features.

[image]

Can anyone suggest me a better approach to tackle this problem? Will any Machine Learning based approach work better? Thanks

Comment: You can add your, question up here http://answers.opencv.org/questions/

Comment: okay, guys, I will post my question in those forums. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @ShankarS Have you tried any preprocessing techniques?

Comment: @JeruLuke, Yes I did. I have updated my question with a thresholded image I got after adjusting some HSV parameters and a bit of median blurring. However, It is getting difficult to process further. Do you suggest of any ML-based approach?

Comment: The preprocessed image looks better. I had the same thing in mind. Don't know if ml based approach would help. How much further do u want to go?

Comment: I want to be able to crop each of these roots separately from the original image and save. That's my final target.

Comment: @ShankarS Its very late but did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cv2.BoundingRect()`, it gets the rectangle area of your contour. Also you can use `MedianFilter` to get rid of "salt and pepper" noise in your picture.

Comment: Using Median filter erodes the root portions as well since they are very thin.

Comment: Seems we are close now. I guess try use Dilate function, it will get your contours thicker. Then just simply search for the biggest contours in the image. You could write a simple logic for that. Just find three biggest contours.

Comment: it works, but the salt n pepper noise in the remaining part of the image gets dilated and creates problems when eroding back for finding the contour. How can I modify the median filter so I can remove only those noise not part of the root?

Answer (score 0):

First step detect big root, by user select or big erosion.
Second step base on previous big area center coordinate, make a fill algorithm (like Paint Bucket Tool in Paint) on this original threshold image

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is, I have several images like this, and some of them have the roots closer by, some of them in a different orientation. I am trying to see if I can write a script to detect in all the images without any user intervention.

Comment: @ShankarS Use cv2.findContours to detect biggest area, and apply the second step a describe before, orientation is not a problem.